# Call a selector that takes a char* from PyObjC

Tags: objective-c, pointers, char, pyobjc

I'm trying to use a private framework with PyObjC.  I've got this so far:

```
from AppKit import *
from Foundation import *
import objc

framework="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework"
objc.loadBundle("DSObjCWrapper", globals(), framework)

directory = DSoDirectory.alloc()
directory.initWithHost_user_password_("server", "diradmin", "password")

eDSStartsWith = 0x2002
node = directory.findNode_matchType_(u"/LDAPv3", eDSStartsWith)
```

That works fine.  Now, I want to call a method on my node (of class DSoNode), with this objective-c signature.

- (BOOL) hasRecordsOfType:(const char*) inType

The most obvious way doesn't know how to take a string and pass it to a char*:

```
node.hasRecordsOfType_("dsRecTypeStandard:ComputerLists")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/clinton/<ipython console> in <module>()

ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'str' of 31
```

It looks like it is possible to change the signature as python sees it.  I tried some variations on:

```
objc.registerMetaDataForSelector("DSoNode", "hasRecordsOfType_", dict( arguments={ 2+0: dict(type_modifier='n', type='^C') }))
```

but--and frankly I don't know how the registerMetaDataForSelector function works, and haven't found docs on it--I still get the same error when I invoke my selector on the node.  How do I tell PyObjC to convert a string to a char*?  (Or is there a better way to do it, as these strings are C constants #defined in a header file.)

---

Update:  I tried using `gen_bridge_metadata` (as mentioned [in this blog post](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2007/10/27/pyobjc-20-pyobjc-in-leopard/)), and, after consulting the man page, tried it as follows:

```
sudo mkdir -p /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Resources/BridgeSupport
sudo gen_bridge_metadata --framework ~/Downloads/DSTools-112.1/build/Deployment/DSObjCWrappers.framework/ --output /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Resources/BridgeSupport/DSObjCWrappers.bridgesupport
```

I still get the same error; there is no indication that this was even noticed, except that if I type:

```
help(modules)
```

I get:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Versions/A/Resources/<ipython console> in <module>()

NameError: name 'modules' is not defined
```

I should also mention that I found a list of types that I believe would be understood by the registerMetaDataForSelector function; [objective-C type encodings](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html).  Note that the XML for the particular function I'm after says:

```
<method selector='hasRecordsOfType:'>
<retval type='B'/>
</method>
```

I would've expected something explaining the input parameter, too.

Comment: Use c_char_p to pass the c-string (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the following and then should pass a non-unicode string:

```
objc.registerMetaDataForSelector("DSoNode",
                                 "hasRecordsOfType:",
            dict(
                arguments =
                {
                    2: dict(type=objc._C_PTR + objc._C_CHAR_AS_TEXT,
                            c_array_delimited_by_null=True,
                            type_modifier=objc._C_IN)
                }
            ))
```

---

A more complete NSString example follows:

```
from AppKit import *
from Foundation import *
import objc

def setupMetadata():
    objc.registerMetaDataForSelector("NSString", "stringWithCString:",
        dict(
            arguments =
            {
                2: dict(type=objc._C_PTR + objc._C_CHAR_AS_TEXT,
                        c_array_delimited_by_null=True,
                        type_modifier=objc._C_IN)
            }
        ))

def doTest():
    s = NSMutableString.stringWithString_(u"foo");
    NSLog(u"string[" + s + "]")

    s2 = NSString.stringWithCString_("bar")
    NSLog(u"string[" + s2 + "]")

setupMetadata()
doTest()
```

Comment: (Sorry for the belated reply).  This really looks like it is on the right track.  With both examples, I get:  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_C_CHAR_AS_TEXT'

Comment: Woohoo!  When I used objc._C_CHR, it works!  I suspsect _C_CHAR_AS_TEXT comes from a version of PyObjC newer than the one that ships with Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call hasRecordsOfType like so:

```
from ctypes import *

typeString = c_char_p('dsRecTypeStandard:ComputerLists')
node.hasRecordsOfType_(typeString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I try it, I get:

ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'c_char_p'